# webpack-cli init Command not found

Tags: webpack

I have webpack v4 and webpack-cli installed via npm. I am running this command...

```
webpack-cli init
```

I keep getting an Unknown command 'webpack-cli error? This is my package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
  "webpack": "^4.1.1",
  "webpack-cli": "^2.0.11"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `webpack-cli` globally in order to use it like that:

```
$ npm i -g webpack-cli
```

if you don't want to install it global you can use `npx`

```
$ npx webpack-cli init ...
```

[npx](https://github.com/zkat/npx) helps to execute local packages.